# Ignore an IndexError in Python2.7 without continue statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except, continue

I have a try and except statement within a for loop. I am looking at data stored in a (perhaps over complicated) list that itself is stored in a defaultdict. I expect IndexErrors, but when they occur I simply do not need to compare any data, so I want to ignore the error. Here's my current code:

```
for key, list_item in defdict.iteritems():
    if len(list_item) == 2:
        if len(list_item[0][1]) > 1 or len(list_item[1][1]) > 1:
            compare00,compare01=[],[]
            if another_list.__contains__(list_item[0][0]):
                try:
                    for item in defdict.iteritems():
                        if item[1][0][0] == list_item[0][0]:
                            compare00.append(compare_function(item))
                except IndexError:
                    continue
            if another_list.__contains__(list_item[1][0]):
                try:
                    for item in defdict.iteritems():
                        if item[1][1][0] == list_item[1][0]:
                            compare10.append(compare_function(item))
                except IndexError:
                    continue
        print compare00,compare10
        #etc
```

I have since realised the `continue` statement is not correct. My `if` statements needn't be mutually exclusive, therefore, neither going to the next iteration of the loop (`continue`) nor leaving the loop (`break`) are appropriate. A blank `except IndexError:`, *i.e.*, without the `continue`, is incorrect syntax. How should I ignore the error?

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear. by "I don't want to move on" I meant I want to execute more code within this iteration of the loop, hence neither `break` nor `continue` are desired. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pass` statement instead of `continue` statement

Comment: Or even anything that is valid code but doesn't evaluate to change anything

Comment: `break` will help then

Comment: See comment RE: `break` under the question.

Comment: This was the answer I needed. I previously had only used `pass` for a placeholder. Didn't think of it here, but it works perfectly. For info: [pass documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue the loop then use [`pass`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm) not `continue`.
If you want to stop the loop then use [`break`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm) not `continue`.